# Unable to differentiate between file add and file delete using Dropbox API on Python

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've written a python script to check for file additions / deletions from a Dropbox folder. The [delta API](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.6-docs/#dropbox.client.DropboxClient.delta) says that

> Delta Entries: Each entry is a 2-item list of one of following forms:
>
> [path, metadata]:

or

> [path, nil]

Each entry refers to a file that has changed (created/modified/deleted)

The metadata attribute is non`nil` when the file exists in the Dropbox folder, and it is `nil` when it does not, ie when it has been deleted (or so I understand. Correct me if I'm wrong)

So to find files that been *created* I can iterate over the list of entries and check if the second attribute of each entry is non`nil`.

However, after deleting files from the Dropbox folder when I do

```
for entry in next_cursor['entries']:
    print entry[0]
    print entry[1]
```

it prints

```
./filename
None
```

ie, `None`, instead of `nil`. So I did a string comparison for 'None' instead of for 'nil', but even though entry[1](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.6-docs/#dropbox.client.DropboxClient.delta) was 'None' the comparison failed. This is baffling me.

My whole code is as follows.

```
import dropbox
import sys

access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)

curr_cursor_file = open("cursor.txt", "r")
curr_cursor = curr_cursor_file.read()
curr_cursor_file.close()

next_cursor = client.delta(curr_cursor)
#print next_cursor
curr_cursor_file = open("cursor.txt", "w")
curr_cursor_file.write(next_cursor['cursor'])
curr_cursor_file.close()

if len(next_cursor['entries']) > 0:
    for entry in next_cursor['entries']:
        if entry[1] != "None":
            print "File added!"
            print entry[0]
            print entry[1]
        else:
            print "No new files have been added. But files have been removed."
else:
    print "No files have changed."
```

ie, even when `entry[1]` prints `None` it shows that `File has been added!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `None` is a special constant whose value is commonly known as the `null` or `nil` value.  For some reason, the DropBox documentation uses the term `nil` in this case instead of Python's term `None`.

Note that `None` is not a string.  `None == "None"` will return false.  So where you have `entry[1] != "None"` you need to use `entry[1] != None` instead.

Comment: `if entry[1]` or `if entry[1] is not None` are probably more idiomatic Python. With regards to the documentation, I'll make sure that gets updated in the next release of the Python SDK.